# How to know if the MacBook Pro is having dual core or Quad core?

Tags: macbook-pro

What do dual or quad core mean and how do I know which one I have in the Mac.

In the hardware info I see the processor name "6-Core Intel Core i7". But I expected Quad core means only 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do dual or quad core mean

Dual meaning 2 and quad meaning 4. This indicates the number of physical cores present in the processor.

> how do I know which one I have in the Mac

Go to Apple Menu (top right corner on your Mac) → About This Mac and click on the System Report... button. In the window that is presented, click on the Hardware item at the top in the left column. On the right, you can see the processor type and the number of cores present in it.

[image]

Comment: So, a 6 core processor is more powerful than Quad core?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter A 6 core processor is just what it says, i.e. a processor with 6 cores. It depends on the OS and the applications whether they leverage multiple cores or not. A 6 core processor would be better than 4 for cases where an app is programmed to make use of multiple cores.

Comment: It's also "better" if the application uses only 4 cores, leaves 2 cores for others :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can look up detailed spec for all Mac models on [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/index-apple-specs-applespec.html). For [MacBook Pro 16-Inch "Core i7" 2.6 2019](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.6-six-core-16-2019-scissor-specs.html) you'll find

[image]

Comment: I think we cannot just use website because MACs are customizable in some places like in India I guess

Comment: @firstpostcommenter You can customize Macs all over the world. But the choice of processors is limited, and they are listed on the site.

Comment: yes so to know the exact processors used within the respective mac, we need to check it in MAC's system info rather than in a website I think

Comment: @firstpostcommenter There are usually no more than 3 choices of CPU for a particular year model of Mac laptop.